# reading from an already open if stream object

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I have a text data that is three lines only

```
100,200,300,400, John
300,400,500,100, Abraham
600,500,500,200 , David
```

I want to go and read this line by line and save it in a map

This is my code and i can not get the correct output..

```
 void save_details ( map < vector<int> , string >m , ifstream dets ) {

     int a , b , c , d;
     string s;
     while ( dets >> a >> a >> c >> a >> s) {

         vector<int>mine.push_back(a);
         vector<int>mine.push_back(b);
         vector<int>mine.push_back(c);
         vector<int>mine.push_back(c);

         m.insert(pair<vector<int> , string>(mine , s));
     }
  }
```

How will i correctly and efficiently store those data in a map

Comment: `ifstream` is not copyable, you cannot pass it by value. Pass it by reference instead.

Comment: Those commas will get you.  You'll read the first number just fine, but >> will try to read the comma as the second number. A simple solution is  `char comma;  while ( dets >> a >> comma >> a >> comma >> c >> comma >> a >> comma >> s)`

Comment: Does this code compile? You appear to be redeclaring `mine` four time within your loop, and, as @IgorTandetnik pointed out, ifstream isn't copyable. I would think that both things would keep this code from even compiling. Also are you using a `vector<int>` as the *key* to map? I'm a little lost here.